# Autocomplete method to get me different values

Tags: facebook, targeting

Where I cat to found info about changes the locations to targeting.

Ex: English (All) value returned me as 4 different values.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all locales list here: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=&limit=1000&type=adlocale

I think you are asked about values with key greater than 1000
You can simply find it in the this list: all English, all Chinese etc.